# What general mobius transformation maps $|z-1|=1$ to itself and $|z+1|=1$ to $|w-3|=3$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> What is the most general mobius transformation that maps $|z-1|=1$ to itself and $|z+1|=1$ to $|w-3|=3$.

I want to find the *most general* form of such a linear transformation, I'll denote it $T$. My reasoning is as follows:

The origin must be fixed since the origin in the $w$-plane is the only point where the two concentric circles meet. Hence, $T:0 \to 0$.  Further, the real line in the $w$-plane intersects both circles at right angles, hence it's pre-image must intersect the circles in the $z$-plane at right angles. The only line or circle that does this is the real line in the $z$-plane. Hence, $T: 2 \to 2$ and $T: -2 \to 6$. This defines three points we can use to arrive at the mobius transformation given by
$$
T(z) = w = \frac{3z}{z+1}.
$$
However, my goal is to find the *most general* mobius transformation that does this. Is this form unique?

The reason I think my solution is incorrect is because I was told that there is in fact a family of one-parameter maps that accomplishes this transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D=\{z:\, |z-1|>1,\,|z+1|>1\}\cup \{\infty\}$(the outside of two circles $|z-1|=1$ and $|z+1|=1$) and $G=\{w :\,|w-1|>1, \, |w-3|<6\}$(the region enclosed with two circles $|w-1|=1$ and $|w-3|=3$).
We want the most general mobius transformation $w=T(z)$ which maps $D$ onto $G$.

First we consider $\zeta=f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$. It mapps $D$ to $E=\{\zeta: -\frac{1}{2}<\operatorname{Re}\, \zeta < \frac{1}{2}\}$. Note that the boundary $|z-1|=1$ corresponds to $\operatorname{Re}\, \zeta =\frac{1}{2}$.
Also it is easily checked that $\xi=g(w)=\frac{1}{w}$  mapps $G$ onto the region $F=\{\xi:\,\frac{1}{6}<\operatorname{Re}\, \xi <\frac{1}{2}\}$.  Note that $|w-1|=1$ corresponds to $\operatorname{Re}\, \xi=\frac{1}{2}$.

Now we consider the most general mobius transformation $\xi=h(\zeta)$ which mapps $E$ to $F$. Of cource $h$ must correspond $\operatorname{Re}\, \zeta =\frac{1}{2}$ to $\operatorname{Re}\, \xi=\frac{1}{2}$.
Such a $h$ is \begin{align}
h(\zeta)&=\frac{1}3{}\left(\zeta+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{6}+i\frac{\alpha}{3} ,\quad\alpha \in \mathbb{R}\\
&=\frac{\zeta+1+i\alpha }{3}.
\end{align}
Note that 'most general' is accomplished by translations parallel to the imaginary axis.
Since $T=g^{-1}\circ h\circ f$, we see that
$$
w=T(z)=\frac{3z}{(1+i\alpha )z+1}, \quad \alpha \in \mathbb{R}
$$
is what we wanted.

Comment: Thanks for this. The mathematics makes sense to me but how do you motivate such an approach? For example, how did you know we needed to consider a transformation $h$ from $E$ to $F$?

Comment: To tell the truth, you get almost a correct answer. 
The only one thing you missed is the fact that there are mobius transformations 
$\varphi_\alpha$ which map $G$  onto itself, fixing  $|w-1|=1$ and $|w-3|=6.$ 
If you consider composition of $\varphi_\alpha $ and $T$, 
you get the correct answer $\varphi_\alpha  \circ T$. 
But it is slightly hard to obtain $\varphi _\alpha$ explicitly. On the contrary to obtain the explicit form of translations is easy.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful. Another question: how do you know to choose $D$ and $G$ as you have chosen? It seems a little arbitrary to me. For example, how do you know not to to choose the interior of the two circles in the domain? And why is $G$ chosen to be the space between the two circles in the range?

Comment: Without $D$ and $G$ you can proceed as follows. 
Let $f, g$ be the same in may answer. 
\begin{align}
&f:\, \{|z-1|=1\} \to \left\{\Re\zeta=\frac{1}{2}\right\},\quad \{|z+1|=1\}\to \left\{\Re \zeta=-\frac{1}{2}\right\},\\ 
&g:\,\{|w-1|=1\}\to \left\{\Re \xi=\frac{1}{2}\right\},\quad \{|w-3|=3\} \to \left\{\Re \xi=\frac{1}{6}\right\}.
\end{align}
Therefore $h=g\circ T\circ f^{-1}$ must map  $$
 \{\Re\zeta=\frac{1}{2}\}\to \{\Re \xi=\frac{1}{2}\},\quad \{\Re \zeta=-\frac{1}{2}\}\to \{\Re \xi=\frac{1}{6}\}.
$$
If we determine such a general $h$, $T=g^{-1}\circ h\circ f$ is the one  desired.